# Preventing duplicate class error in Java/IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm writing an interpreter (w. [Crafting Interpreters](https://craftinginterpreters.com/)), and I'd like to preserve the working state of the interpreter after each chapter in the same root folder.

The interpreter's name is jlox, and to preserve its state after chapter 7, I want to duplicate the code in the jlox dir into a jlox[7] dir. See image.

[image]

So, subsequently, I'll duplicate into jlox[Y] dir, where Y = chapter to preserve.

The problem with copying like this is that IntelliJ sees all the classes as duplicates, preventing any code from building. Is there a way/setting to avoid a `duplicate class` error with the added constraint of being able to maintain duplicates of the code base in the same folder?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few things and this worked: making every dir under root a module.

You'll notice in first image (above) that `jlox` is not a module, but `jlox[7]` is. So the fix was to make `jlox` a module as well.